AWS Cloudfront - having to request url 2 to 3 times, otherwise I get a 30s timeout
This works fine when I first hit it:
https://www.mywebsite.com/bff/login-options
< 500ms
But when I hit the URL again, (btw the routing is aws route53 > aws cf > aws lb)
I get a 30s timeout.
I have to hit the url 2 sometimes 3 times, again to get an immediate response.
CloudFront
For a behaviour any path matching /bff/* goes to the alb, otherwise to the s3 bucket. On this same behaviour I have set cache policy to disabled, and origin request policy to all viewer.
Does anyone know why I get the above browser / request behaviour?
In contract, here the responses are all immediate:
https://loadbalancer.com/bff/login-options
